# Banner Slider Not working properly in Magento

Tags: magento

Hello Stackflow Community
I have just added the following banner in my website

http://www.magestore.com/banner-slider.html

I am facing two problems in it

1) Once you have clicked on a bullet, it stops going automatically.

2) When you refresh site, it is not starting with the first bullet.  It starts somewhere in the middle sometimes. This has to be  changed as  it always has to start with first bullet when refreshing the site.

Please guide me if anything have to altered in ajaxtabs.js file

URL for checking the issues, http://www.com/24s/

Comment: Have you [contacted magestore](http://support.magestore.com/) about it?

Comment: Yes i have but no response yet, need some help from your side.

Answer (score 0):

we need to modify ajaxtabs.js file. You need to change in the following lines: - line 130 (near

`"init:function(automodeperiod)"` ): change `"var persistedtab=ddtabcontent.getCookie(this.tabinterfaceid)"` to `"var persistedtab=0"` - line 142 (near `"tabinstance.expandtab(this)"`): change `"tabinstance.cancelautorun()"` to `"// tabinstance.cancelautorun()"` or remove this line.